# SQL Server client for Ubuntu

Tags: database, ubuntu, sql-server

I need to connect to a MS SQL Server database from my Ubuntu machine. Any client suggested? I found [libmono-entityframework-sqlserver6.0-cil](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libmono-entityframework-sqlserver6.0-cil), will that work?

It doesn't sound like just a client:

> Mono provides a complete CLR (Common Language Runtime) including compiler and
>    runtime, which can produce and execute CIL (Common Intermediate Language)
>    bytecode (aka assemblies), and a class library.
>    .
>    This package contains the EntityFramework.SqlServer library for CLI 4.0 which
>    provides Microsoft SQL Server support.

That is maybe too much?

Comment: Do you need a client with a GUI? What do you need to do on the MS SQL Server database, browse the data in tables and issue SQL commands?

Comment: @mguassa a GUI would be nice, but basically I need to send SQL commands, so queries and create and alter tables and schemas and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. Your suggestions sound good but they weren't as easy to start as what I used, which is [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/), a universal database tool for developers and database administrators.

- Easy installation with `.deb` installer, ready to start in 1 minute
- Easy to use
- Free (GPL2), open-source and multi-platform
- It supports MS SQL Server (as requested in the question) and other relational and NoSQL databases

Only feature I couldn't find until now: *generate DDL scripts*

Here's a general UI screenshot taken from its website:

[image]

**UPDATE june 2016**

Been using the tool for some months now and I'm very happy. I am now with version 3.7, and I can generate DDL scripts, which I was missing before. Furthermore, DBeaver also comes as eclipse plugin and I am using it directly from the IDE. Great

Answer (score 1):

If Microsoft are providing a true SQL Server then just about any SQL client ***should*** be able to access it but a lot depends on what you need to do - admin tasks will often need more specialized tools.

Personally, for an SQL client - regardless of the server - I would start with python *which you should already have* and [pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/).

pymssql provides a Python DB-API ([PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)) interface to MS SQL so anything that you build on top of it can work with another database if you change back-end in the future.

- Lightweight
- Customization Possible
- Free
- You can add access methods via various methods but for user exploration [iPython](http://ipython.org) is superb.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), the universal SQL client.

From the website:

> SQuirreL SQL Client is a graphical Java program that will allow you to
> view the structure of a JDBC compliant database, browse the data in
> tables, issue SQL commands etc..

It's open source, and being written in Java it's also multi-platform, i.e. it's available for Linux as well.

According to the FAQ, MS SQL Server is in the [list of the supported databases](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=faq#faq0), as long as the proper driver is installed.

What's a driver?

> A driver allows you to connect to a particular database (Oracle,
> Sybase, DB2, etc.) We cannot legally ship most drivers with SQuirreL
> (in the installer or from the update site) as they are proprietary and
> most database vendors require users to download them directly from
> their website.
>
> In theory SQuirreL should work with any DBMS that has a JDBC 2.0
> driver.

A few screenshots of the program:

[image: SQuirreL SQL - drivers]

[image: SQuirreL SQL - object tree]

[image: SQuirreL SQL - code completion]