# Which software can I use to browse a MSSQL database?

Tags: gratis, gui, ubuntu, sql-server

I want something similar to phpMyAdmin for an MSSQL server.

It MUST have / be:

- M1: a graphical interface where I can see all table names
- M2: [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- M3: work with [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) 16.04

Nice to have would be

- N1: a possibility to see all databases
- N2: possibilities to directly execute SQL queries
- N3: a graphical representation of the relationships of the tables (similar to phpMyAdmin designer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server client for Ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23468/sql-server-client-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, but you could try:
DBeaver

https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) as "Front-end Tool" to get access with all types of DBMS including MS SQL

It is same as phpMyAdmin[image: I am using it for accessing PostgreSQL DB]

Answer (score 0):

teamSQL can work pretty well. get to [TeamSQL site](https://teamsql.io/). Its commercial but does what you expect.

Comment: Can't find teamSQL, the Download footer links redirects to [DataRow](https://datarow.com/) site with a free 14-day trial. Is it the one? If so, it's not free.